# Bot Framework: How to wait for background task?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I would like to run a background task as part of a Bot Framework action, such as running an Azure Automation job or sending an approval request to a human. 
The goal is that the bot should *only* reply to the user once the background task has fully completed, in this case when the Azure Automation job finished successfully or the human has approved the request.

My bot is using a custom DirectLine channel in which it is not a problem if the communication with the user is async, the user will not expect the bot to reply back instantaneously. 
How can I have Bot Framework wait for a background task to complete, **before** sending a response back to the user?

Comment: Have you checked out async/await? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for your response. Yes, I did, but I'm anticipating the wait can be quite long in my case. It can be ranging from several minutes up to hours before the background task completes, depending on the type of automation job or availability of the human. I believe the async/await statements wouldn't keep my bot waiting this long? As my bot is running on Azure Functions, I wouldn't also want to keep the bot logic to actively wait so long, as I'm paying per-second resource consumption. Let me know if I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are looking for is called proactive messaging. First you save the conversation reference and when your background task is complete, you can utilize this reference to send your message.

Microsoft Docs: [Send proactive notifications to users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: Thanks, it seems like this could indeed work! 
Would I still need to send back a message from the bot to the user immediately that says something like "I'm working on this I'll get back to you when I'm done", or is it possible to return nothing at all to the user until the back-end process has finished? I prefer the option where I don't send anything to the user until the proactive message indicates the process has finished, as my channel is similar to mail and it's not necessary that the bot replies instantaneously.

Comment: I think I figured this last question out myself: it looks like I don't have to send a reply right away to confirm the message was received, and I can just forward the message to the external service. Whenever the external service is finished, it can use the proactive message to reply back in the conversation to the user. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little too late for the OP, but may be relevant for others that arrive here.

Few months ago I made a bot that had to wait a background process (to build a report with Power BI Embedded and generate an image of it) and return that image to the user.

In my case, the background process fitted well as an inprocess background service using the [BackgroundService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class as the hosted service, and a custom action to prepare the data and send it to the background service through a [Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1?view=net-6.0).

Finally, when the work is done, the service returns the information to the user using the ContinueConversationAsync method from the Bot Framework SDK.

You can check all the implementation details in my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/MYesca/botframework-customactions). The relevant pieces are the [custom action](https://github.com/MYesca/botframework-customactions/blob/master/PBI/Client/Action/GetQna.cs) and the [service](https://github.com/MYesca/botframework-customactions/blob/master/PBI/Client/Singletons/VisualRenderWorker.cs) itself.